# Use access token from GIDSignIn to use Google Drive SDK iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have set up my project to sign in to a user's Google account using the Google Sign In framework. It works fine, but I want to use the access token that I get from the sign in to access the user's Google Drive. I am programming for iOS and have already set up the Drive SDK in my project. I feel like there should be a simple way of doing this. Thank You!

Answer (score 9):

Recently experienced the same problem myself when attempting to use the Calendar API.

You can access the access token (and therefore use it in your URL Requests) like so:

```
if (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser != nil) {
    let accessToken = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.accessToken
    // Use accessToken in your URL Requests Header
}
```

Make sure to only call this method after the user has signed in, the check for current user will prevent a crash from implicitly unwrapping a nil value.